# Linear independence of a generating set of a finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G = C_{10} \times C_{10} \times C_{10} \times C_{10}$, where $C_{10}$ denotes the cyclic group of order 10. Suppose I have 4 explicit elements, say $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ of G, each of whom have order 10 and I know that those actually generate G, then how should I prove this theoretically. In general, is there a way to prove the linear independence of prospective generators for any $G = C_{n} \times C_{n} \times \ldots \times C_{n}?$

Comment: You show that it holds mod 2 and mod 5, both of which are vector spaces. More generally, use the Smith Normal Form.

Comment: @ahulpke. Thanks for your response. Can you please explain what do you mean by mod 2 and mod 5. Suppose I start with assuming 
 x1^{a1} x2^{a2} x3^{a3} x4^{a4} = 1. Then I need to prove all $ai$ are 0.

Comment: mod 2 means you consider the exponents modulo 2. That is in the factor group by $C5xC5xC5xC5$, this factor is a 4-dim vector space over the field with 2 elements. mod 5 in the same way for the two primes swapped.